# jquery masonry combine photo and text

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

[image]

Hi there,

I'm using Jquery Masonry to display a series of photos and caption/title on soccer news. 
I would like to show news title as having same width as uploaded photo so subsequent photos can be align to its right empty space rather than top down alignment such as attach picture.

Any idea how this can be done? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found the answer. I was comparing to Masonry version 2 which uses "col1", "col2", etc for its box width. Apparently I don't see this feature in latest version of Masonry version 3.

I've decided to use CSS to limit a box width

```
<style>

.box{
    width: 300px;       
}

</style>
```